# How to display link in checkbox label in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I wanted to display a link inside react-bootstrap check box label as per attached image how to format the tags in side label? please help.

```
<Form.Check
    className="checkbox-groove"
    label="I agree to the {<a>terms and conditions</a>}"
    name="group1"         
  />
```

[image]

https://codesandbox.io/s/display-link-inside-a-input-label-0vosse

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass a react component to the label prop [react bootstrap docs](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/forms/checks-radios/#form-check-props) like so:

```
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Form.Check
        className="checkbox-groove"
        label={
          <span>
            I agree to the <a href="#">terms and conditions</a>
          </span>
        }
        name="group1"
      />
    </div>
  );
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/display-link-inside-a-input-label-forked-jzusxj